# Why iterating over a Pytorch dataloader never ends and goes forever?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have created a dataloader whose length is 50000. When I calculate its length it prints out 50000.

```py
class MyDataLoader(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_size=50000):
        self.data_size = data_size

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.data_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx) -> t.Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        image, label = my_function()#(has_star=True)
        return image[None], label
dl = MyDataLoader()
print(len(dl))
50000
```

However, when I iterate over it, it goes forever like the following:

```py
for j, i in enumerate(dl):
  if j%10000 == 0:
    print(j)
10000
20000
30000
40000
50000
60000
...
```

How is that possible?

Comment: j%0? Why are you doing a modulo against 0? No number divided by zero gives a result in the set R. What are you trying to do? This means that no number modulated by zero by 100000

Comment: @Davide: that was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using enumerate instead of range(len(d1))?

Comment: See colesburry's reply in this thread: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-my-custom-dataset-class-loop-forever/50785/3
@ShadowGunn you can't use range(len(dl)): TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: @ShadowGunn: I want to access the number of iterations that is why I use enumerate.

Comment: @Davide: my dataloader inherits form torch.utils.data.Dataset and according to the post you referred to should stop at the end of length, but it did not.

Comment: try switching j and i around @Sepide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a `Dataset`, not a `Dataloader`.

This should work:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_size=50000):
        self.data_size = data_size

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.data_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # print(idx)
        return idx

dataset = MyDataset()
# Assume a default batch size of 1
dl = DataLoader(dataset)
print(len(dl))

for j, i in enumerate(dl):
  if j%10000 == 0:
    print(j)

# And with a different batch size:
dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2)
print(len(dl))

for j, i in enumerate(dl):
  if j%10000 == 0:
    print(j)
```

Note how `len(dl)` changes when the batch size changes.